# Connection between difference quotient and gradient descent update rule

Tags: gradient-descent, finite-differences

The difference quotient of a function is defined as

$$w'(t) = \frac{w(t)-w(t-dt)}{dt} = \frac{w_{t}-w_{t-1}}{dt}$$

and as $dt$ approaches zero gives the derivative of function $w$.

Now, the update rule in gradient descent is defined as

$$w_{t} = w_{t-1} - \eta \frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{t-1}}$$

I wonder, if $dt$ is the same as $\eta$? Is there any connection between these two expressions? And is it possible to derive the gradient descent update rule from the difference quotient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, your expressions already hint at the connection. For a finite, but small $dt \equiv \eta$ you have

$$
w' \approx \frac{w_t - w_{t-1}}{\eta}
$$

or equivalently

$$
w_t \approx w_{t - 1} \color{red}{+} \eta w'
$$

which is basically your first equation in 1D. Here's the catch though: the gradient points toward the direction of maximum growth of the function $w$, so if you're trying to minimize it (hence the name *gradient descent*) you want to move in the opposite direction, that's is, you want to flip the sign $\color{red}{+}$ to $\color{red}{-}$, that is

$$
w_t \approx w_{t - 1} \color{red}{-} \eta w'
$$

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting! However, the learning rate $\eta$ is sometimes relatively large and $w'$ therefore a rough approximation. Is there a better way to approximate $w'$ then?

Comment: @Samuel that's a fantastic question, turns out the answer is not that trivial, e.g. a large $\eta$ will allow you to move fast through parameter space, but it may skip the actual minimum. A small value, on the other hand, can take you ages before it converges. Here are a few links you may enjoy reading [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.11162), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization)

Comment: I just wonderd where $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{t-1}}$ has gone in your explanation. Did you assume $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{t-1}} \approx w'$?

Comment: @Samuel there's a bit of a confusion in your notation, in the first Eq. the independent variable is $t$ and the function you want to optimize is $w$. In the second equation, the independent variable is $w$ is the one you want to optimize is $L$